# Simple progress for rsync when piping output to a log file

Tags: logging, rsync, nohup

I ran `rsync` with `nohup` and `--progress`:

```
nohup rsync --progress --[other-options] source destination &
tail -f nohup.out
```

When I'm tailing the file, I see the output with a ***changing*** last line (where the progress is being shown):

```
folder/file.ext
    40469819 100%    2.74MB/s    0:00:14 (xfer#1, to-check=10076/10079)
```

But when I open `nohup.out` in a text editor, I see **every change** as a separate line:

```
folder/file.ext
       32768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00
     2523136   6%    2.10MB/s    0:00:17
     3702784   9%    1.63MB/s    0:00:22
     7372800  18%    2.22MB/s    0:00:14
     9994240  24%    2.28MB/s    0:00:13
    13107200  32%    2.47MB/s    0:00:10
    16384000  40%    2.97MB/s    0:00:07
    19070976  47%    2.73MB/s    0:00:07
    22642688  55%    2.91MB/s    0:00:05
    25722880  63%    2.94MB/s    0:00:04
    28934144  71%    2.91MB/s    0:00:03
    32178176  79%    3.06MB/s    0:00:02
    35422208  87%    2.98MB/s    0:00:01
    38240256  94%    2.92MB/s    0:00:00
    40469819 100%    2.74MB/s    0:00:14 (xfer#1, to-check=10076/10079)
```

I'm worried this could quickly grow the `nohup.out` file and eat up my disk space.

Is there a way to make `rsync` show a simple progress indication, like this?

For 55% (my imaginary `rsync` is simply appending characters for each percentage):

```
folder/file.ext
===='===="===='===="===='===="===='===="===='===="
===='
```

When done, it would show the same summary for 100%:

```
folder/file.ext
===='===="===='===="===='===="===='===="===='===="
===='===="===='===="===='===="===='===="===='===="
    40469819 100%    2.74MB/s    0:00:14 (xfer#1, to-check=10076/10079)
```

This way the `nohup.out` would not bloat (especially for large files), and would have the same content as what's shown when I tail it.

Possible or any alternatives? I saw `--log-file` option (a bit too late) I'm not sure if it will be helpful (can I still monitor the progress by tailing the log file?)

**Edit:** I have tried the `--log-file` option (don't add `--progress`; if you use `-P`, change it to `--partial`). Although it logs some useful progress to the log file, it won't show the percentages. It's good enough as long as you don't care about the percentage.